# Unable to bind <select> in cshtml file with knockout ViewModel

Tags: javascript, razor, model-view-controller, knockout.js

This is my ViewModel code

```
var urlPath = window.location.pathname;


$(function () {
    ko.applyBindings( CreateVM);
});
var CreateVM =  {
EmployeeId : ko.observable(),
  Name : ko.observable(),
    Genders: ko.observableArray(["Male", "Female"]),
    Gender: ko.observable(),
   City:ko.observable(),
   SaveEmployee :function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: urlPath + '/Create',
            type: 'post',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: ko.toJSON(this),
            contentType: 'application/json',
            async:true,
            success: function (result) {
                window.location.href = urlPath + '/Employees/Index';
                alert("success in createVM");

            },
            error: function (err) {
                if (err.responseText == "success") {
                    window.location.href = urlPath + '/Employees/Index';
                    alert("sucess in error in createVM");
                } else {
                    alert(err.responseText);
                    alert("error in createVM");
                }
                alert("message");
            },
            complete: function () {

            }
        });
    }
};
```

And this is Create.cshtml  tag which is neither getting prepopulated nor retrieving the value. All other fields like EmployeeId , City and Name are getting retrieved properly .

```
<div class="editor-label">
    Gender
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    <select data-bind="options: Genders,value: Gender "></select>
</div>
```

Comment: I think either your claim that the other fields work, or your repro isn't quite precise enough. I think `Genders` should work just fine, and `Gender` might if the others work too. Can you provide a [mcve], extend the code a bit perhaps?

Comment: At any rate, one potential problem: you use `this` inside the `Save` function. But it'll not refer to the view model, but to the nearest function scope instead. Try using a constructor function for your view model, or alternatively add the functions *after* declaring the var so you can use a reference to that var instead of `this`.

Comment: Thanks for having a look at my problem.I just made a temporary fix by giving <options> in cshtml file instead of initializing the array in js file. That works for now but I still do not get why the above code doesnt work . I will try to add more information.